# htaccess redirect conflict issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having an issue with conflicting quert strings on a page. for instance the page can look like the following:

website.com/photos/type/album-name/page-2/
AND
website.com/photos/type/album-name/photo-id/

the issue here is that I don't know how to make it so that it knows that when it says 'page-2' that it takes one rule, and when it's the photo-id it takes another.

I have the following

```
RewriteRule ^photos/([\w+.-]+)/([\w+.-]+)/([\w+.-]+)/?$ /photos.php?view=$1&slug=$2&page=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^photos/([\w+.-]+)/([\w+.-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /photos.php?view=$1&slug=$2&pid=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Are those the only two URIs, exactly, that the RewriteRule is concerned with? If so, the rewrite is too vague and the second one appears to be incorrect (only matching digits at the end). If it is just for those two URIs specifically, then we can suggest a tune up of your regex to get it working, most likely.

Comment: @arkigos, those are the only two scenarios for this page. Just those two urls. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having different rewrite rules for every possible query string, why don't you have a generalized rewrite and handle the query strings in your application?

Or, for your second query, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^photos/([\w+.-]+)/([\w+.-]+)/(page\-[0-9]+)/?$ /photos.php?view=$1&slug=$2&pid=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Your URLs would look like,

website.com/photos/type/album-name/page-2/ --> with the 'page-' keyword.